# На работает getline

Tags: c++

getline срабатывает только на первой итерации.Все осталные пропускается.Все библиотеки подключены

```
while (1)
{
string select;
print(M);
cout << "Enter names of drink or exit:";
getline(cin, select);
if (select == "exit" || select == "EXIT")
    break;
else
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (M[i].name == select)
        {
            y = i;
            break;
        }
        else if (i == size - 1)
        {
            cout << "Input error\n";
        }
if (y == -1)
    continue;
else
money+=buying(M, y, size);

}
```

Comment: читает  строку, а не слово

Comment: В чем выражается "Все осталные пропускается"?

Answer (score 0):

Функция getline читает до первого символа новой строки. Тоесть, если вы хотите ввести несколько слов, то делайте это в одну строку.